# Filter pipe does not effect ngModel value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create two select dropboxes that one filters the other in angular.

1st select:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption1">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options1" [ngValue]="option.value">
    {{option.description}}
  </option>
</select>
```

2nd select:

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption2">
   <option *ngFor="let option of options2 | filterOption2ByOption1:selectedOption1" 
           [ngValue]="option.value">
            {{option.Category2Name}}
   </option>
 </select>
```

options1:

```
options1 = [{
   description:"option 1-1",
   value:1
  },
  {
   description:"option 1-2",
   value:2
  }]
```

options2:

```
options2 = [{
   option1Value:1,
   description:"option 2-1",
   value:1
  },
  {
   option1Value:2,
   description:"option 2-2",
   value:2
  }]
```

pipe looks like this:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterOption2ByOption1'
})
export class FilterOption2ByOption1 implements PipeTransform {

 transform(options2: any, option1Value: number): any {
  if(option1Value !== null && option1Value !== undefined){
   return options2.filter(option => option.option1Value == option1Value)
  }
  return null;
 }
}
```

what doesn't seems to work is that after the filter does its magic the `ngModel`
does not change.

`click` event nor `[ngModelChange]` are triggered if I trying to add them to 2nd select.

the pipe works fine. the only problem is that the `ngModel` is not effected by it.

Comment: how is selectedOption1 is defined?

Comment: for now it is not but can easily be defined as `selectedOption1 = options1[0].value` @JayDeeEss

Comment: `Pipe`s are not supposed to change the model. They're only scope is to format a view value.

Comment: how would you suggest implementing it? another attempt I tried is to call function `ngModelChange` triggers on 1st select that will filter options2. but pipes seems to be much more cleaner to me... if this isn't their purpose how should I do it? @Hitmands

Comment: As a side note, Angular team discourages the use of pipes for filtering or ordering. You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

Comment: very  enlightening. thank you. @BogdanC